# How to fetch Azure ID Token to use for authorization within webapi?

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm

We are about to run D365 CRM in Azure and now we are trying to find out how to authorize a call to our onprem api.

The scenario is simplified like; A user is saving an annotation in D365 CRM and when that happens we also want to make a call to our onprem api.

We want to make the call using the Azure ID Token (to be specific NOT Access Token). This is to authorize the user when accessing the api.

Is it possible to get the ID Token and send that with the call? We have so far only managed to pick up the Access Token which is not good enough. How should we do to retrieve the ID Token?

Comment: An access token acquired with user context does contain the signed-in user's info, and that is what you should be using. The Id token is always only meant for the app that requested sign-in.

Comment: Could you show how you acquire the access token?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing fundamental concepts of OAuth / OpenID Connect. You **must** use an `access_token` when calling an API. The purpose of `id_token` is not make **authorization** decision in an API, but to obtain basic information about the user in Client App.

You can find a [really good formulated and compact article on the subject here](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis).

When you have the `access_token` and when it is the proper one, it includes all the information you need:

- Which is the calling application
- **Who** is the acting end user
- What authorizations (application roles or scopes) are granted

Any additional information (that could be part of the id_token) can be obtained using the Microsoft Graph on the back-end side of your API.

Here are some more references that will be helpful:

- [Microsoft Identity Platform `id_token` reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens)
- [Microsoft Identity Platform `access_token` reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)

Pay attention to the claims references in both token types.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I read some more about the different types of token and realised that what I really wanted was the user access token but so far we only received application access token. I think we did find a way today that resolves our issue.